# Facebook + iOS - post link without dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, iphone-sdk-3.0, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using facebook-ios-sdk in my iphone application

I am trying to post a link on facebook from my iphone application

```
NSLog(@"link..%@",[shareDict objectForKey:@"url"]);
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [shareDict objectForKey:@"url"], @"link",nil];
[facebookObj requestWithMethodName:@"facebook.Stream.publish" andParams:params
    andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

it successfully posted as my application log

```
2011-03-30 13:10:02.128 myApp[1804:207] link..http://khabar.ndtv.com/Home.aspx
2011-03-30 13:10:04.064 myApp[1804:207] received response..https://api.facebook.com/method/facebook.Stream.publish
2011-03-30 13:10:04.066 myApp[1804:207] request didLoad.. . . API..thod/facebook.stream.publish
```

But link is not showing on facebook wall... it shown as..

[image]

Now

- How I post the link with out showing dialog
- How I it as like in facebook .. as user have option to select the image from link with out any dialog.. I can use my own view for it. like as
  [image]

Comment: I have add the message object in params Dictionary then its shown in facebook.. now how I add the description of link and image(if any) in the link ..

Comment: try using stream.publish instead of facebook.stream.publish  and  Check out this link:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/

Comment: To add link and image use this: NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"http://check.com/image.png", @"picture",
                               @"http://yourlink.com", @"link",                       @"CAption of the Image comes here", @"caption",
                               @"Description here", @"description",
                               @"MESSAGE COMES HERE", @"message",
                               nil];

Answer (score 0):

Here's my FB arguments snippet:

```
[fbArguments setObject:theName        forKey:@"name"];
[fbArguments setObject:theCpation     forKey:@"caption"];
[fbArguments setObject:theDescription forKey:@"description"];
[fbArguments setObject:theLink        forKey:@"link"];
[fbArguments setObject:theHREF        forKey:@"href"];
[fbArguments setObject:thePictureURL  forKey:@"picture"];
```